# blue/green deployments with traefik/docker possible?

Tags: docker, traefik

We're using a docker swarm with traefik for a few dozen services/sites. We are running into a bit of an issue with javascript apps using vue/vue-cli and chunking. The resources for these sites are loading through build-time urls (like:  app-23233234.js).  This means when we deploy a new site with replicas, when the first host is added to the swarm, there is a chance that the resources will be loaded from an older instance where the resources have a different name.

The result is that every time we deploy, the site becomes unstable for a bit.

The solution would be a way to have a blue/green deploy, where all the replicas for the new deploy are brought online, and then in 1 command the frontend on traefik is pointed to the new set.

It this possible with traefik? Ive tried a few different things but can't really find a way to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't that still break users that pull resources from blue and then start to talk to green? The build time URLs should be designed to have new URLs added to the same host with older URLs. I'd try thinking about this from another direction. Perhaps a fallback on 404s to the older instance.

Comment: I can see responding to a 404 working in a blue/green setup, where a 'blue' js client would refresh when it gets a 404 because the service switched to green. I guess you could even automate that with a ping-like route. But the problem is that spinning up 20 replicas and spinning the old ones down takes time, and during this switchover the 404 idea kind of breaks down. 

I think there really isn't a very sane way to deal with this except making sure the URLs dont change like they do, and thus ditching the idea of using vue-cli chunking. This problem wouldnt exist with query string cache bust.